# String/Array in Java

Tags: string

Does this work? I'm trying to print a message in this.

```
char[] tempMessage = message.toCharArray();     
    String[] message2 = message.split(" ");          
    Integer.toString(number).toCharArray(); 
    for(int x = 0; x<newMessage.length; x++)
    {

    }
```

Comment: how should punctuation be treated? Should "Hello, world!!" output "H5w5" or "h6w7"? Perhaps we should be splitting on word boundaries, not white space.

Answer (score 2):

Although its better to use a `StringBuilder`, I can show it using String(s).

```
String[] strArr = "hello world".split("\\s+");
String s = String.valueOf(strArr[0].charAt(0))+strArr[0].length()+String.valueOf(strArr[1].charAt(0))+strArr[1].length();

Output : h5w5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] message2 = message.split("\\s+");
String output = "";
for(int i = 0; i < message2.length; i++)
{
    output += "" + message2[i].charAt(0) + message2[i].length();
}
//output has output string.
```

Answer (score 1):

TheLostMind's solution is already good, but I think it needs a solution for Strings of arbitrary length.

```
String outputString = "";
for(String x : message.split("\\s+"))
{
  outputString = outputString.concat(x.charAt(0) + x.length());
}
```

As stated in the comments, this solution is very similiar to brso05's solution. The difference is in using the :-Operator in the for-loop. It's shorter and IMHO easier to understand, as it says 'for each String in the resulting array'.
Also, using the concat()-function is considered safer in my work environment.

Comment: @brso05 I'm sorry, started typing before you posted. Still, it's different from yours and needs one line less.